# VLOOKUP every word in a cell to perform Abbreviation decoding

Tags: excel, text, vlookup

### Want to Provide Decode Multiple Abbreviations Using Formulas

I have a table of cells made up of all "abbreviation" words, and I would like to provide an explanation of them, using a lookup table.   Either VLOOKUP, INDEX(MATCH) or an array formula is preferred to a Macro.

**Main Table:**

```
Column A | Column B                 | Column C
Part No. | Description              | DESIRED OUTPUT
ABC101   | CAL 40 UKE WH RD         | California 40" Ukelele White Red 
ABC202   | DLX 55 GTR BK BL         | Deluxe 55" Guitar Black Blue
ABC303   | CAL HD 40 VIO RD BL      | California Hot Dog 40" Violin Red Blue
```

The abbreviations could be in any order, and some might be absent.

**LookupTable:**

```
Column J | Column K
Abbrev   | Expansion
CAL      | California
DLX      | Deluxe
UKE      | Ukelele
GTR      | Guitar
VIO      | Violin
WH       | White
BK       | Black
RD       | Red
BL       | Blue
40       | 40"
55       | 55"
etc.
```

I guess I could split the "Column B" Description into multiple columns (using <kbd>MID(FIND(" ")</kbd> -- not "Text to Columns: Delimited"), then look up each one, ignore blanks and errors, and concentate the result, but I'd like to do that in a single uber-formula.  Possible?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Where this is possible if one has TEXTJOIN, vba would be a much better tool.

Comment: I currently have Excel 2016 with Excel Web and Google Sheets as available alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for providing a data example as text. Makes it easy to copy/paste into Excel.

How about a not so uber formula:

I added HD to the abbreviation list and used a **Table** for that list (makes it easy to add, change, remove without worrying about adjusting references).

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,
       INDEX(tblAbb[Expansion],
               MATCH(TEXT(
                          FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"),"@"),
                             tblAbb[Abbrev],0)))
```

[image]

[image]

**Algorithm**

- `FILTERXML` returns an array of the individual abbreviations
- `MATCH` returns an array of the row numbers of those abbreviations in the abbreviation table.
- `INDEX` uses the array returned by `MATCH` to return the Expansion strings.
- `TEXTJOIN` joins that array together with a `space` separator between each expansion.

Comment: Thank you, this was a very clearly explained solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to do that in a single uber-formula. Possible?

Of course! Piece of cake! Uber-formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<a><b>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2;" ";"</b><b>") & "</b></a>";"//b[1]");$G$2:$H$12;2;0) & " ";"")
& IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<a><b>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2;" ";"</b><b>") & "</b></a>";"//b[2]");$G$2:$H$12;2;0) & " ";"")
& IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<a><b>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2;" ";"</b><b>") & "</b></a>";"//b[3]");$G$2:$H$12;2;0) & " ";"")
& IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<a><b>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2;" ";"</b><b>") & "</b></a>";"//b[4]");$G$2:$H$12;2;0) & " ";"")
& IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<a><b>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2;" ";"</b><b>") & "</b></a>";"//b[5]");$G$2:$H$12;2;0) & " ";"")
& IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<a><b>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2;" ";"</b><b>") & "</b></a>";"//b[6]");$G$2:$H$12;2;0) & " ";"")
& IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<a><b>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2;" ";"</b><b>") & "</b></a>";"//b[7]");$G$2:$H$12;2;0) & " ";"")
& IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<a><b>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2;" ";"</b><b>") & "</b></a>";"//b[8]");$G$2:$H$12;2;0) & " ";"")
```

Numbers in lookup table should be stored as numbers not text.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was a very clearly explained solution.